# How do you say "Welcome to English", as in welcome to English class?

Tags: translation

How do you say "Welcome to English", as in welcome to English class?

Comment: （热烈）欢迎（你们）学英文，欢迎 is usually followed by a verb, as in （热烈）欢迎（你）来中国

Comment: *欢迎 is usually followed by a verb,* No, 欢迎 (welcome) is a verb, is usually followed by a noun (object)

Comment: ＂followed by a verb did not necessarily mean immediately＂ but just as in below answer 欢迎 is followed by verb 學習 (with adverbial complement 第一次 in between), of course one can say 欢迎 is followed by NP (noun phrase) followed by a predicate, but NP can be omitted just as in answer, translating e.g. "welcome to China" would seem to involve a verb like 来

Comment: Subject and object are omitted because it is understood that who they are, either from previous context, or it is obvious on in itself -- A teacher's greeting to his class: " Welcome to  English leaning."  should actually be: " (I ) welcome (you all) to  English leaning." Even subject "I" and the object "you" were omitted,  they are still implied.

Comment: preceding comment would seem to belabor the obvious, superfluous for users of this site

Comment: Just don't want users to be misled to believe "*欢迎 (welcome) is usually followed by a verb*"  which is incorrect. There are instances that subject and object can't be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a title of a book, it can be translated as  "英語入門"

If it is a greeting from a teacher to his class, it means " 歡迎第一次學習英語。" = "Welcome to English learning for the first time."

Beside the above examples, the phrase " Welcome to English" doesn't provide enough context to be meaningful.